# Cassandra: Insert with older timestamp

Tags: cassandra, cql3

(Cassandra 2.0.9, using CQL)

I've accidentally updated a row in a table which was managing its own timestamp (100 * a specific sequence number). Now, because my timestamp is the current time, none of the updates are working. I understand why this is, but I'm trying to recover from it. I'm fortunate that I can delete these rows.

I've set **gc_grace_seconds** to 0 and run **delete from *table* where key=*primarykey*** to remove the rows. After, I've used **nodetool flush** and **nodetool compact** *on every node* to cause the deletion to go through and get the resulting tombstones compacted and erased.  I've then bumped **gc_grace_seconds** back up to 10 days and tried to **insert into** a row with the same key but *using timestamp 1* .

This doesn't work. Just wondering if anyone has done a similar mistake and worked around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I would give this exercise a try.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:presentation> SELECT * FROm bladerunners WHERE id='B26354';
 id     | data                | name         | ts                       | type
--------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------
 B26354 | Filed and monitored | Rick Deckard | 2015-02-16 12:00:03-0600 | Blade Runner

(1 rows)
```

Here is a look at how the data is stored, using the `cassandra-cli`:

```
[default@presentation] get bladerunners[B26354];
=> (name=, value=, timestamp=1427744637894310)
=> (name=data, value=46696c656420616e64206d6f6e69746f7265642e, timestamp=1427744637894310)
=> (name=name, value=5269636b204465636b617264, timestamp=1427744637894310)
=> (name=ts, value=0000014b938c09a2, timestamp=1427744637894310)
=> (name=type, value=426c6164652052756e6e6572, timestamp=1427744637894310)
Returned 5 results.
Elapsed time: 7.67 msec(s).
```

I will now delete the `data` column for this row, generating a tombstone:

```
DELETE data FROM bladerunners WHERE id='B26354';
```

When I SELECT with `tracing on` I can see that the column shows "null" and I have a tombstone out there.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:presentation> SELECT * FROM bladerunners WHERe id='B26354';

 id     | data | name         | ts                       | type
--------+------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------
 B26354 | null | Rick Deckard | 2015-02-16 12:00:03-0600 | Blade Runner

...

Read 1 live and 1 tombstoned cells [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2015-06-10 08:42:25.858000 | 192.168.23.129 |           2173
```

So I will set the `bladerunners` table's `gc_grace_seconds` to zero:

```
ALTER TABLE bladerunners WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;
```

From the (Linux) command line, I will flush and compact my `presentation` keyspace:

```
aploetz@dockingBay94:/local/dsc-cassandra-2.1.4$ bin/nodetool flush
aploetz@dockingBay94:/local/dsc-cassandra-2.1.4$ bin/nodetool compact presentation
```

When I SELECT with `tracing on`, I can see that the `data` column is still "null," but now the tombstone is gone.

I will now re-INSERT the `data` column with a timestamp of 1:

```
INSERT INTO bladerunners (id, data) VALUES ('B26354','Filed and monitored') USING TIMESTAMP 1;
```

When querying with the `cassandra-cli`, this is now what I see:

```
[default@presentation] get bladerunners[B26354];
=> (name=, value=, timestamp=1427744637894310)
=> (name=data, value=46696c656420616e64206d6f6e69746f726564, timestamp=1)
=> (name=name, value=5269636b204465636b617264, timestamp=1427744637894310)
=> (name=ts, value=0000014b938c09a2, timestamp=1427744637894310)
=> (name=type, value=426c6164652052756e6e6572, timestamp=1427744637894310)
Returned 5 results.
Elapsed time: 4.7 msec(s).
```

Note that the `data` column now has a timestamp of 1.

Try running your query with `tracing on` and see if your tombstones are really gone.  Also, check your table via the `cassandra-cli` to see how the timestamps are coming through.  Let me know if you need clarification on any of these steps.

**NOTE:** I was just showing the flush/compact as part of the example or exercise.  I feel compelled to mention that DataStax recommends that users ***avoid*** manually running `nodetool compact` if at all possible.

Comment: Crazily this is what I was doing to no avail. I'm happy that I was going down the right path.  How big of a cluster were you running against?

Comment: @Idcmp Yes, it's just my little one-node sandbox.  Have you tried running a `nodetool repair`?  If it is node/cluster related, that should help.

Comment: @Idcmp Also, what do you mean by "This doesn't work"?  Are you seeing an error?  And is your column value(s) showing "null" or just displaying an old value with the incorrect timestamp?

Comment: I'm on a slightly bigger cluster, and you're right I may not have run repair along the way. By "doesn't work" I meant that my insert using timestamp 0 never winds up being accepted by the cluster.

I've temporarily worked around the issue, but I do want to fix it the way we're both trying. I'll give it another shot over the next few days.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that it seems on a clustered Cassandra, one must run flush/compact against each node. Doing that does make this solution work and I feel this is more likely what others in my situation would want, so I'm marking it correct.  Thanks!

Comment: @Idcmp  I admit, it's not ideal.  I was more showing the flush/compact as part of an example.

Answer (score 1):

BryceAtNetwork23's answer is likely the "most correct", it does come with a caveat that **you must run nodetool flush and nodetool compact on every node** (or so it seems from my testing of 3 node Cassandra cluster). This can take a prohibitively long time.

As another solution (for those visiting here in the future), you can acquire the rows you ultimately want to delete.

```
cqlsh> select id from example_table where some_field = -1 allow filtering;
```

Then dump that to a file used to delete the rows in question.

```
cat cassandra-output | sort | uniq | grep '^ ' | grep -v id | gawk '{ print $1 }' >just-ids.txt
cat just-ids.txt | gawk '{ print "delete from example_table where id='\''"$1"'\'' and some_field = -1;" } >remove.cql
cqlsh ... -f remove.cql
```

I found [Cassandra Dump](https://github.com/gianlucaborello/cassandradump) which I then use to dump the remaining data.
After that I can drop and recreate the table (and indexes if needed), then reload the data.

Lastly, I can insert rows I had, but with new timestamps:

```
cat just-ids.txt | gawk '{ print "insert into example_table (id,some_field) values('\''"$1"'\'', -1) using timestamp 0;" }' >repair.cql
cqlsh ... -f repair.cql
```

If you're doing this repeatedly you can of course just drop the table and reload it with the post-repair data. It's a faster solution when you're repeatedly reloading than doing flush/compact.